# Drupal 8: reference to a block created with views in a paragraph (as field)

Tags: drupal-8, paragraph, drupal-blocks, paragraphs, entityreference

I want to do add a field as reference to a bloc in a paragraph.
The block was created using Views module.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least tow ways :

1 - Using [Views field formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_formatter)

2 - As views in Drupal 8 are entities you can use entity reference field to link the view then expose it in your template

Comment: I don't like it the idea of the module itself, maybe i have to try the second way. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, we can use entity reference field, choose block type. Maybe a disabled attached block, or i found a some one else solution by creating a region named "hidden" that will be not used in template but just to get the block in autocomplete of the referenced field.